# vba send email and print as pdf and save to folder?

Tags: excel, vba, email, pdf

I have an excel workbook like so:

```
Column B                         Column Q

C:\Folder1\File.xls              email
C:\Folder2\File.xls              email
C:\Folder3\File.xls              email
```

When i run the macro below, it sends an email to each recipient in column Q. It also attaches each of the corresponding attachments in colum B in each email it sends out.

```
Sub email23()

'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("Q").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value) <> "" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .subject = "Attention Required: Promotion Announcement for Week " & Range("O10").Value & " " & Range("O13").Value
                .Body = "Good " & Range("A1").Value & "," _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                      "Thank you for your interest in participating in this weeks special promotion. Please see the details below." _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                                     & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                      & Range("D10").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                      & "Thank you and kind regards / Danke und freundliche Grüße," _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                      & "The Food Specials Team" _
                      & vbNewLine

                'You can add files also like this
                .Attachments.Add (cell.Offset(0, -15).Value)
                .Send  'Or use Display

            End With

            OutMail.PrintOut

            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This works fine, but now i want to print my sent email and save it as pdf into the same folder as the attachment.

So far i have tried printout but this doesn't seem to do anything. Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely late, but I came to this thread when googling for a solution to a problem similar to yours.

One thing I noticed is that

```
OutMail.PrintOut
```

comes after

```
End With
```

, which may be causing the issue.